# Wired Connection issue

Tags: networking

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Lenovo G580 series had an issue with the ethernet this was solved after installing Atheros network driver. The laptop was working fine and able to do browsing, but after installing the updates(around 200MB) the problem started again wired detecting but unable to connect to it.

Please look into this.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the Atheros network driver (or any kernel module) from source, then after a kernel upgrade, you must recompile and reinstall the module against the new kernel version.

In your specific case, note that recent 12.10 kernels have got built-in support for various Atheros cards, including the AR8162 which is likely to be in your G580. This card is supported by the **alx** kernel module.

If you previously had a module installed from source, you may want to attempt to `sudo make uninstall` it, to (hopefully) undo any blacklistings its installation script may have put in place.